# Creating a simple filter in Meteor

Tags: filter, meteor, client

I would like to filter a collection of posts based on a list that various posts belong to. I have a dropdown that allows users to select the list but cannot figure out how to only show posts that are associated with that list.

Each post right now has a list name and id that is being saved with it - and I am able to present the available lists.

All I need to do right now is a simple filter so a user can basically "view" only posts for a given list.

Here's where I'm at - if I could pass an id from the select into postlistid - just haven't figured out how to do this. I tried using a variable and getting the value in an event change on the list passed through to the helper but again not quite connecting the dots.

```
    Template.userPostsFiltered.helpers({
      userfilteredposts: function() {
      var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
          return Posts.find({userId: currentUser, postlistid: { $exists : true }}, {}, {sort: {date: -1}},{reactive:true});
     }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: When the user selects the list, set a session variable in the event map. Then use the same session variable in your `userfilteredposts` helper.

Comment: Ah ok, awesome, thanks man. I knew I was missing something super simple. This is the danger of noobs like me attempting to build something like I am the first time out.

Comment: So one question about setting a session variable. If I have: <option value="{{postlistid}}">{{postlistname}}</option> and I want to pass postlistid through as a variable then do I use this as the session variable?

Comment: Ok so I set the session id. When it renders (I'm using created) then the session variable gets sent through. BUT on change nothing happens. It sets the session variable but doesn't seem to re-render and filter the posts. I thought if you passed through a variable and that changed it would auto re-render?

Comment: Please update the question with all relevant code that you have so far (template, helpers, events). Alternatively I can give a complete example, but to be perfectly frank, I've avoided spending a lot of time on this because you don't have any accepted answers.

Comment: Something you said earlier just hit me in a roundabout way so actually all good. I realized I needed to do this in template rendered.

Comment: Have a look at the example in my answer - you can run it by creating an empty project and inserting those two files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete working example:

### posts.html

```html
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> userPosts}}
</body>

<template name="userPosts">
  <h2>Post Lists</h2>
  <select>
    {{#each postLists}}
      <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>

  <h2>Filtered Posts</h2>
  <ul>
  {{#each filteredPosts}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

### posts.js

```js
Posts = new Mongo.Collection(null);
PostLists = new Mongo.Collection(null);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var pl1 = PostLists.insert({name: 'List 1'});
    var pl2 = PostLists.insert({name: 'List 2'});
    var pl3 = PostLists.insert({name: 'List 3'});

    Posts.insert({postListId: pl1, name: 'A'});
    Posts.insert({postListId: pl1, name: 'B'});

    Posts.insert({postListId: pl2, name: 'C'});
    Posts.insert({postListId: pl2, name: 'D'});

    Posts.insert({postListId: pl3, name: 'E'});
    Posts.insert({postListId: pl3, name: 'F'});
  });

  Template.userPosts.helpers({
    postLists: function () {
      return PostLists.find();
    },

    filteredPosts: function () {
      var postListId = Session.get('selectedPostListId');
      return Posts.find({postListId: postListId});
    }
  });

  Template.userPosts.events({
    'change select': function (e) {
      var postListId = $(e.currentTarget).val();
      Session.set('selectedPostListId', postListId);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks yeah the session variable did the job I ended up creating different templates for my filters. But thanks for sending this through - I see some stuff I should probably implement.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. :) Side note - I'd strongly recommend [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) some of your answers in order to get better responses in the future.